# Execute script tag in js

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to execute javascript from another script tag so for example:

```
 <script>
    script 1 
    execute script 2 from other script tag here after first script is completed
 </script>

 <script>
    script 2
 </script>
```

Comment: You could include the script again to run it, but that's silly. Just call whatever function is in script2.

Comment: Tried that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you include the code that demonstrates that "it doesn't work"?

Comment: What is the exact problem here? What is the error you are getting? More context is needed here.

Comment: Try calling an external js file via ajax.

Comment: The second function is not executed when called. The code is avaliable here:

Comment: http://codeshare.io/nCQNM

Comment: Which of the scripts in that large collection is script 1 and which is script 2?

Comment: If you want to call a function from script 2, you have to include it before script 1.

Comment: Script 1 is in first between line 5 and 684, Script 2 is between 685 and 1337

Comment: You have (at least) two seemingly identical scripts after eachother. Too much code to wade through

Answer (score 0):

If script 2 is inline, you can do this:

```
<script>
  function1() {
    ...
  }
  window.onload=function() {
    function1(); 
    function2(); 
  }
</script>
<script>
function2() { ... }
</script>
```

Comment: How would I execute the second function. When I tried doing this it executes only second function and not first:

<script>
level1();
level2();
....

Ideally I want to run second function and stay there when this code is executed: 

if (player.y == 27 && player.x >= 66 && player.x <= 82) {
    level2();
  }

Comment: When I debug it the way you showed me it goes into that function, goes through it quickly and steps back to function 1, where I want to stay in function 2

Comment: First clean up the script

Comment: Tried using your method and <script src="level1.js"></script> but that still doesn't work